# How do I tell my simple_form object to return an array with just the selected IDs and not any empty values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a simple_form object that looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :parents, collection: (@node.family_tree.nodes - @node.parents - [@node]).uniq, as: :check_boxes, label: "Parent 1" %>
```

This produces HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="node_parents">
<label>Parent 1</label>
<input id="node_parents_13" name="node[parents][]" type="checkbox" value="13" /><label>Jack</label>
<input id="node_parents_35" name="node[parents][]" type="checkbox" value="35" /><label>Testy</label>
<input id="node_parents_37" name="node[parents][]" type="checkbox" value="37" /><label>Resty</label>
<input id="node_parents_36" name="node[parents][]" type="checkbox" value="36" /><label>Mesty</label>
<input name="node[parents][]" type="hidden" value="" />
</div>
```

When I fill out 2 of the 4 objects, my log looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F1HGLwIjDG3VaIYlnsu7NbROEiWBO8xqJtjh5MreI9E=", "node"=>{"name"=>"Lesty", "parents"=>["13", "35", "", ""], "family_tree_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update Node", "id"=>"38"}
```

Rather than it sending the `params[:parents]` as a 4-element array with 2 empty/nil values, I would rather it just send a 2-element array.

How do I do that?

Comment: Try this, params[:parents].delete_if {|key,value| value.blank?}

Comment: That is filtering them out in the controller, he asked how to not send the empty values in the first place.

Comment: That's an interesting solution @Sontya. I would do that in the `Post#Update` right?

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Yes max you are correct, I thought if he just don't want to save that data to database. So this can be a solution.

Comment: @Sontya I had to use `params[:node][:parents]` instead..because there was no `params[:parents]`. The issue is that now it seems to be deleting the entire array if 1 value is blank, as opposed to deleting just 1 key.

Comment: @marcamillion - Oh yes, I did't seen those lines clearly Try this, this will reject the element which are empty `params[:node][:parents].reject!{|p| p == ""}` or `params[:node][:parents].reject!(&:blank?)`

Comment: @Sontya That works perfectly. Can you add an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @marcamillion - glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
params[:node][:parents].reject!{|p| p == ""}
```

or

```
params[:node][:parents].reject!(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you really need to change what is sent by the form, or if you can just filter out the blank values in the controller before doing anything with them?

If you *do* want to avoid sending empty values then you will need to do something with javascript on form submit, to alter the params from the form before they are submitted.  It's definitely much simpler to let the form submit the blanks and filter them out in the controller, however.

To do it with javascript, you'll need to do something like this: i'm assuming you're using jQuery here.  The approach i have chosen is to change the submit button so it calls a function instead of submitting the form.  The function disables the empty inputs (thus not including them in the form data) and then submits the form.

Add a js function to the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var processForm = function(){
    //disable unchecked checkboxes
    $("#myForm input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#myForm").submit();
  };
</script>
```

then replace your submit button with this:

```
<%= button_to_function "Submit", "processForm();" %>
```

Comment: Yeh this seems very complicated. If I wanted to filter the blank values in the controller before doing anything with them, then I would simply add that line of code that Sontya said to my `Node#Update`?

Comment: Yep, that looks like it will work.  The only reason i can think that you might want to use my approach is if you are going to have hundreds of checkboxes and don't want the request to get too large.  Otherwise, do it in the controller.

Comment: Yeh....I don't have that issue here. Just tried that and it seems to be deleting all the values. Will have to look at it more deeply.